# performing php post with jquery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am trying to run [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

i did not implement the validation part yet, but my problem shouldn't be based on this. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitbutton").click(function () {
  var content = $.("#contentarea").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addArticle.php",
    data: content,
    success: $.("#addArticle").append("<p>ok</p>")
  });
  return false;
})
</script>
```

As seen in the demo, it should not refresh the page because of the return false statement and also should do a post instead of get. But neither it does. It will continue to reload the page and also append the given content to the url as an argument. How do i prevent this / where is my failure?

[Here is the whole thing](http://pastebin.com/iZue8X5L)

Comment: And it is better to use event.preventDefault() instead of return false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you have followed is incorrect. There are more ways to submit a form than just clicking on its submit button (for example, you can press <kbd>return</kbd> while in a text field). You need to bind your code to the form's `submit()` event instead of the button's `click()` event.

Once you have done this, use your in-browser debugger to check whether the code is actually being run when you submit the form.

Also, the `success` parameter needs to be a function:

```
submit: function() { $("#addArticle").append("<p>ok</p>") }
```

**EDIT** : also, you have written `$.(` instead of `$(` several times. This will cause a runtime error, which may cause the code that blocks the submission to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Well well well...

A few less nerves later, it works. 
I decided to use the [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started)

But, and i bet you'll love that, i have no idea why it is working:

```
        <script> 

        $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#addForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("ok"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 

    <div id="addArticle">
        <form id="addForm"  method="post" action="addArticle.php">

                <textarea id="contentarea" required="required" name="content">    </textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">
        </form>
    </div>
```

I guess the author has done pretty good work, just wanted to tell my solution to that future guy who is searching on google for that problem.